# Monitor traffic via image to third party sites

Tags: php, html

I want to check how many people view my personal space on an online market place, I have the ability to upload an image to my own space on their domain so I was think I would be able to upload an image on my domain, and link this using the  tag and then from my domain I would some how view how many times the image has been downloaded (to view the page).

Can anyone point in the right direction on how I could go about setting something like this up, I have seen some image status that do a similar thing but I would like to use my own custom image so people may not notice that I'm tracking who views it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP you are able to render a custom self drawn image or just load one from a file.

You can use these functions for drawing:

[PHP - GD and image functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

When rendering the image you can do other things, for example log things to a database table or a text file. This way you are able to count the image downloads, and have statistics about many other things.

When returning images you must make sure that no other output goes to the client. (Don't echo anything in the middle od the image data.) You need to send a special header too, telling the client's browser about the content type, and other things.

You could display a static image from a file like this in PHP:

```
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
readfile($file);
// Then log what you want
```